# Regex get text between tags

Tags: java

I try to get the text between a tag in JAVA.

`

```
<td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">HELLO TOTO</td>
 <td>Function :</td>
```

`

I would like to use a regex to extract "HELLO TOTO" but not "Function :"

I already tried something like this

`

```
String btwTags = "<td colspan=\"2\" style=\"font-weight:bold;\">HELLO TOTO</td>\n" + "<td>Function :</td>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td(.*?)>(.*?)</td>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(btwTags);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(group);
        }
```

`

but the result is the same as the input.
Any ideas ?

I tried this regex `(?<=<td>)(.*?)(?=</td>)` too but it only catch "Function:" 
I don't know of to set that he could be something after the open `<td ...>`

Already thanks in advance

Comment: Is the source XHTML? If so, i would use a XML parser and XPATH.

Comment: try Jsoup library, please find below link 
https://jsoup.org/

Comment: use group(2); to get the content inside the tag

Comment: Thanks 
`<td([^>]+)>` works but catch all the line `<td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">HELLO TOTO</td>` 
is it possible to only catch `HELLO TOTO` ?

Thank you @Aelop with group(2) it's working :) !

Comment: you can pretty easily check your regex here https://regex101.com/

Comment: Try `"<td.+?>(.*?)</td>"` and `matcher.group(1)`

Comment: XML cannot be 100% parsed using regexes. Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use RegEx to parse HTML, its a very bad idea...

to know why check this link:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

you can use  [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.8.2.jar) to achieve this :

```
String html; // your html code
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
System.out.println(doc.select("td[colspan=2]").text());
```

Comment: This link, again. Using RegEx isn't always a bad idea, just like Jsoup isn't always the correct answer. If your HTML is broken, e.g. with non-closed tags, your parser might choke.

Comment: @EricDuminil Here we assume the HTML is well formed, (otherwise won't be html). also you can spend hours and create a perfect regex which can be probably borken with certain input examples.

Comment: If you download HTML from somewhere on the web, you actually need to assume it isn't well formed.

Comment: @EricDuminil hmm that's might be true, but for the last 2 years that I've been using Jsoup (and I use it alot) , I never had a problem that it couldn't parse a page and give me accurate results. beside, this is considered a good practice so why defy something simple like this and go about create the problem more complicated.

Comment: I've never had a parser "choke". They will usually throw an exception on malformed documents.

Comment: @m0skit0 : What's the difference? You don't get your desired String, even though a Regexp might have extracted it.

Comment: @nafas : Jsoup is perfectly fine. I just don't agree with the statement that it always should be used, and that RegEx is always a bad idea.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm suggesting to use the right tool for the job, RexEx is extremely powerful but for  html tags they are over complicated and hard to formulate...

Comment: @EricDuminil Regex is not the right tool for this. If you use it for parsing HTML, you will eventually regret it. Trust me, I've been down that path several times.

Comment: You both win. Next time I'll use Jsoup first, and a RegEx only if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex for very basic HTML parsing. Here's the easiest Java regex I could find :

```
"(?i)<td[^>]+>([^<]+)<\\/td>"
```

It matches the first td tag with attributes and a value. `"HELLO TOTO"` is in group 1.

Here's an [example](https://regex101.com/r/GJV60A/2).

For anything more complex, a parser like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) would be better.
But even a parser could fail if the HTML isn't valid or if the structure for which you wrote the code has been changed.

Comment: *"if the structure for which you wrote the code has been changed"* Then the parser does not fail, but you do :) Also "fail" is relative. Is throwing an exception "failing"?

Comment: @m0skit0 : I meant that the HTML might be written by someone else, and the whole HTML structure could be changed without further notice.

Comment: Still I don't see what that has to do with the "parser vs regex" question.

Comment: @m0skit0 With some luck, the regex would still find its way to the required tag, even if the structure around it has changed.

Answer (score -1):

I had provided solution without using **REGEX** Hope that would be helpful..

```
public class Solution{
  public static void main(String ...args){
    String str = "<td colspan=\"2\" style=\"font-weight:bold;\">HELLO TOTO</td><td>Function :</td>";
    String [] garray = str.split(">|</td>");
    for(int i = 1;i < garray.length;i+=2){
      System.out.println(garray[i]);
    }
  }
}


Output :: HELLO TOTO             
          Function :
```

I am just using split function to delimit at given substrings .Regex is slow and often confuse.

cheers happy coding...

Comment: Then why not use C! Don't use Java, it is slow and often confusing.

Comment: [`String#split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-): "Splits this string around matches of the given **regular expression**."